# Extracting token from the URL and sending a post request using Axios - Vue js

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, axios

I have been trying to extract a token from say `http://test.com/confirm?token=MMsndiwhjidh...` and then send a post request to another server.

I have tried this:

```
export default {
    data() {
        return {
            confirmation : false,
            somethingWrong: false       
        }
    },
    
    created: function() {
        axios.post('/confirm', null, {
            method: 'post',
            params: {
                token:this.$route.query.token
            }
        })
        .then(function(res) {
            console.log(res)
            this.confirmation = true       
        })
        .catch(function(error) {
            console.log(error)
            this.somethingWrong = true
        })
    }
}
```

I got the following errors:

[image: Error log]

[image: Error log]

I think I am not able to extract the token properly.

Comment: Have you tried arrow functions in your `.then`? The `Cannot set property...` error could be due to the scope of `this`. The other errors are hard to tell without seeing your backend code

Comment: How can rectify cannot set property error

Comment: Try arrow functions the way @Kapcash has answered

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason is you're using declarative functions instead of arrow functions in your then / catch blocks. The `this` don't refer to the same thing (here, `this` is not your Vue component).

Try like this:

```
.then((res) => {
    console.log(res)
    this.confirmation = true       
})
```

I won't try to explain the difference myself as there are plenty of articles on the web about it. [Here's one](https://dmitripavlutin.com/differences-between-arrow-and-regular-functions/#:%7E:text=Understanding%20the%20differences%20between%20regular,this%20of%20the%20outer%20function.)